# Is it possible to duplicate a standby database on the fly?

Tags: oracle, rman

Can I duplicate a standby database on the fly?

Currently, I'm getting this error:

> RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 01/08/2021 01:55:58
> RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
> RMAN-03015: error occurred in stored script Memory Script
> RMAN-06136: ORACLE error from auxiliary database: ORA-01152: file 3
> was not restored from a sufficiently old backup

When I run:

```sql
DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE TO clone_db FROM ACTIVE DATABASE;
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/rman-duplicate-from-active-database-feature-in-oracle-11g/  https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2#:~:text=12c%2C%20All%20Articles-,Introduction,with%20a%20different%20file%20structure.

Comment: you should use "DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE for standby  FROM ACTIVE DATABASE;" if you want a standby database. then this error should not occur.

Comment: @DmitryDemin, I'm asking about using stand-by DB as source..

Comment: @habad You can use standby as source for other standby. 1. Create backup standby database using rman .Copy backup +archive log to new standby host.2. restore database from backup. 3 recover database from archive log. 4 create standby controlfile on primary host 'ALTER DATABASE CREATE STANDBY CONTROLFILE AS '/tmp/db3_stby. ctl'; ' 5 Configure tnsnames.ora on primary and new standby . 6 Configure LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_3 on primary host. 7 Start standby listener and standby database on new host

Comment: @DmitryDemin, thank you, i'm asking about my error why duplicating standby to open - no idea how to deal with this...

Comment: @DmitryDemin, i try to create cloned open database as result of duplicate standby target.

Answer (score 1):

> Step 2: Mount or Open the Source Database Before beginning RMAN
> duplication, mount or open the source database it if it is not already
> mounted or open. If the source database is open, then archiving must
> be enabled. If the source database is not open, and if **it is not a
> standby database**, then it must have been shut down consistently.

[Duplicating a Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV010)

> To create a standby database with the DUPLICATE command you must
> connect as target to the primary database and specify the FOR STANDBY
> option. **You cannot connect to a standby database and create an
> additional standby database.**
> [Basic Concepts of Standby Creation with RMAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/rcmbackp.htm#SBYDB4980)